# Place child over parent with z-index via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where i want to place a child item *over* it's parent, but this somehow seems impossible. For a quick situation check, see this example

http://jsfiddle.net/Mr3bH/

When i hover the parent, i assumed that i re-defined the child css settings (remove the element from its parent, so to remove the parent>child relation) via the line

```
$('#e11').fadeIn().css({position:'absolute',left:'50px',bottom:0,zIndex:15});
```

As can be seen in the jsfiddle example, i want element `#e11` to hover above the `#e1` and `#e2` elements.

Does anybody know a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of the z-index css property is not very easy to grasp at first, since there are several rules involved - in your case changing the z-index is not enought since each of your absolutely positioned **div** element with a z-index property creates a new stacking context, a sort of "layer", and the z-index of its contained elements is only valid in the same stacking context.

A pair of articles that provide some more insight on the matter:

- http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context_example_1

Going back to your example, if you remove the z-index from divs, leaving only the one you set explicitly through jQuery, and you'll see that it will work.

(keep in mind that it is very possible that some browser do not behave as expected since there are - or used to be - quite a few anomalies regarding the interpretation of the z-index property between different broswers)